# how to put an Array of images into specific UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, parse-platform

I'm currently developing a App thats home view controller shows a display of all the users friends, their names and their profile images (if they have one), each within a cell of a  UICollectionView. I am using tags to identify the UI elements within each cell and Parse as the backend. Each user and their relations are stored under the class "User" and then their profile images (if they have chosen one/taken one) are stored under another class called "UserImage". I've managed to set their usernames to the cells but having difficulty with the images. Basically each cell is downloading the entire image array, which I believe is causing the app to crash with this error. Also as soon as the user adds a friend without a profile picture the app seems to act strange..

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]
```

here is how I save the image to parse.. This is in the users profile view controller.

```
-(void)uploadImage {

    NSData *fileData;
    NSString *fileName;
    NSString *fileType;

    UIImage *newImage = [self scaleImage:self.image toSize:CGSizeMake(340.0,340.0)];
    fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
    fileName = @"profileimage.png";
    fileType = @"profileimage";

    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:fileData];

    [file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
        PFObject *userImage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserImage"];

        [userImage setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
        [userImage setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
        [userImage setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
        [userImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error saving image");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Image Saved");
            }
        }];
    }];

}
```

I then query for the current users relations within the *viewWillAppear:* method of the HomeViewController.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];

    self.friendsRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"friendsRelation"];

    self.friends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *query = [self.friendsRelation query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            [self.friends addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}
```

Setting the amount of cells to the amount of the users friends..

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.friends count];
}
```

And finally setting up the cells within the *cellForItemAtIndexPath:* method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell.tag == 0) {

        UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:25];
        cellLabel.text = user.username;

        PFImageView *homeImageView = (PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:50];
        [homeImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        homeImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        homeImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7;

        self.friendImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        PFQuery *imageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserImage"];
        [imageQuery whereKey:@"user" containedIn:self.friends];
        [imageQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {

                //need a statement that defines whether a friend has an image or not, if they do then load that image into their cell, if not then set default image

                [self.friendImages addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                PFObject *imageObject = [self.friendImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"file"];
                homeImageView.file = imageFile;
                [homeImageView loadInBackground];

                NSLog(@"Retrieved %d images", [self.friendImages count]);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
            }

        }];

    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! keep in mind I'm only a couple of weeks into learning iOS..